# Scanning DVWA with sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I set up sonarqube according instructions (https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Get+Started+in+Two+Minutes) and scan DVWA application. But Sonarqube was not able to find most of vulnerabilities. Even simple sql injections. I wonder did I miss some configuration or SonarQube is not able to detect sql injections and other unsecure coding (vulnerabilities)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SonarPHP doesn't have many security rules, and you are more than welcome to suggest new rules in [this google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube)